# Is a copper plane a good antenna?

Tags: rf, antenna, emc, pcb-antenna

It is said that the size of a 1/4-wave antenna is approximately one-quarter of the wavelength of the desired frequency. I saw also somewhere that it can also be longer than 1/4 and it will also receive/emit the desired frequency.

The antennas that I know look like straight wires (like the antenna on my car).

If the antenna was a square (1/4-wave) of the same size, would it be as good as an antenna as a straight wire?

---

EDIT:

The problem is about EMI and how to limit the radiation.

I have the following circuit:

[image]

The blue part is the switching node. It varies from Vin (voltage) to ground and Vin/2 (voltage). It switches at a "high" frequency (~100 kHz.)

Depending on the layout, the switching node can be thin like a trace or can be large as a square.

Depending on the number of layers, there can be a ground layer below the switching node, but there can be no ground layer also.

The system considered will not move.

Comment: Well there is nothing secret. I have a board where I have a copper plan which is a switching node. It moves from ground to Vin (and Vin/2). I was wondering if it was better to  make it thin or large, or actually does it change something in term of antenna.

Comment: Even including harmonics, the fastest IGBTs commutate in some 10s of ns. Please tell me your switching node is significantly smaller than 1m across!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Patch antennas are basically large copper pours.

A rectangular copper pour on one side and a ground plane on the other side can form a patch antenna. Not as simply as that but, well, this is the idea.

The operation frequency is determined by the height (the dimension along the feed direction) and the radiation pattern is determined by the width (the dimension perpendicular to the feed direction):

[image]

NOTE: I tried to illustrate a top-side view. And I assumed there's a ground plane on the bottom side.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does it work without a ground plane ?

Comment: @Jess Patch antenna /wout ground plane is possible but has some problems like less directivity and less selectivity (or higher BW). Because the ground plane basically works as a reflector so without reflection you'll get an omni-directional antenna.

Comment: Interesting :) !

Comment: There's always a ground plane somewhere. If you just stick this in the end of a piece of coax, the coax shield becomes your, well, it's not a plane anymore, but "counterpoise" is the proper term here. In that case, you get something like an asymmetrical dipole.

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is about EMI and how to limit the radiation.

The solution would be use of EMI filters and shielding.

[image]